# What's the best practice for manually installing groovy on Ubuntu Lucid?

Tags: ubuntu, groovy, ubuntu-10.04

What is the best practice if I wanted to download the latest binaries from Groovy website and install?

1. Which location to copy it to? (/usr/share/groovy?)
2. How add groovy to the PATH variable? (needs to be available for groovy shell scripts in cron jobs, so adding to .bashrc or .profile is not preferred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it in /usr/share/groovy and then create symlinks in /usr/bin to the groovy bins should be a good way of installing it.

If you want groovy-1.7.8, there is a debian package that probably works with ubuntu 10.04

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download